# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod unable to write to output file?

Tags: powershell, logging, invoke

I have been able to get this to work and outputs to a screen, but I want to write this to a text file..

Courtesy of: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/3iced0/gettomcat_status/

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$result=$scriptPath+'\results.txt'
New-Item -ItemType file $result -Force


function Get-TomcatStatus{
     param(
         $tomcatserver ,
         $tomcatport = 8080,
         $tomcatuser = "user",
         $tomcatpassword = "pass"
     )
     #Get Credentials into the right format
     $tomcatpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $tomcatpassword -asplaintext -force
     $cred = New-object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist ($tomcatuser,$tomcatpassword)

     #Invoke the restinterface 
     $TomcatStats = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://$tomcatserver`:$tomcatport/manager/status?XML=true -Credential $cred

     $threads = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("threadInfo") | ? {$_.currentThreadCount -ne 0}

     $Memory = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("memory") 

     $requestInfo = $TomcatStats.GetElementsByTagName("requestInfo") | ? {$_.bytessent -ne 0}

     #Populate output object
     $Output = New-object PsObject
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Server" -Value $tomcatserver
     Add-Content $result "Server $tomcatserver"
     #Memory
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_Used" -Value $memory.total
     Add-Content $result 'Memory_Used'+ $memory.total
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_free" -Value $memory.free
     #Add-Content $result 'Memory_free '+$memory.free
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Memory_Max" -Value $memory.max
     #Add-Content $result 'Memory_Max '+$memory.max
     #threads
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Current_Threads_busy" -Value $threads.currentThreadsBusy
     #Add-Content $result 'Current_Threads_busy '+$threads.currentThreadsBusy
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Current_Thread_Count" -Value $threads.currentThreadCount
     #Add-Content $result 'Current_Thread_Count '+$threads.currentThreadCount
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Max_Threads" -Value $threads.MaxThreads
     #Add-Content $result 'Max_Threads '+$threads.MaxThreads
     #requestInfo
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Request_Max_ProcessingTime_ms" -Value $requestInfo.maxTime
     #Add-Content $result 'Request_Max_ProcessingTime_ms '+$requestInfo.maxTime
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Request_Count" -Value $requestInfo.requestcount
     #Add-Content $result 'Request_Count '+$requestInfo.requestcount
     $output | add-member -type noteproperty -name "ProcessingTime_total_s" -Value $requestInfo.processingTime
     #Add-Content $result 'ProcessingTime_total_s '+$requestInfo.processingTime

     Return $output
 }

Get-TomcatStatus SERVER1
Get-TomcatStatus SERVER2
Get-TomcatStatus SERVER3
Get-TomcatStatus SERVER4
Get-TomcatStatus SERVER5
Get-TomcatStatus SERVER6
```

The issue I am trying to get working is that I can write to the output file the following line, just fine:

```
Add-Content $result "Server $tomcatserver"
```

But, wrting integers to the output file does not work:

```
Add-Content $result Memory_Used [string]$memory.total
```

What I should be seeing is something like:

```
Server                        : SERVER1
Memory_Used                   : 1948254208
Memory_free                   : 820702992
Memory_Max                    : 1948254208
Current_Threads_busy          : 1
Current_Thread_Count          : 27
Max_Threads                   : 150
Request_Max_ProcessingTime_ms : 156454
Request_Count                 : 669515
ProcessingTime_total_s        : 88929596
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Tip: you should use `$result = Join-Path $scriptPath 'results.txt'`.

Comment: It seems to work fine with writing strings, but cannot write integers to the log file, for example: `Add-Content $result 'Memory_Used'+ $memory.total`

Comment: Can you include in your Q the current output you get in the file?

Comment: Done..  Thanks for that.  I have clarified the question and results.

Comment: Try with `Add-Content $result "Memory_Used $($memory.total)"`?

Comment: Awesome!  Works great,  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either use

```
Add-Content $result ("Memory_Used: " + $memory.total)
```

or

```
Add-Content $result "Memory_Used: $($memory.total)"
```